# Where to save a txt file in my android app to late read from it and overwrite it?

Tags: java, android

I want to have a .txt file that I can access from inside my application, but I don't have an idea of where to put it, so I can overwrite it later.

Can someone give me a tip for solving this dilemma?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Can you give more information on what the file will be used for?

Comment: is to keep track of a number(Long)

Comment: For that you might find shared preferences simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the .txt file supposed to be there before the APP Starts or when the App is running.

if the .txt file is going to be created after the App has started, you can just create directories to keep it in a specific place you want it to be in.

If the file is supposed to be there when the App is starting, you can create a /assets folder in your workspace folder and call this function:

Context.getAssets().open("");

For overwriting, are you going to add more information on top or totally change the information inside, because there might a difference in implementation depending on what you gonna do to it.. you need to be abit more specific

Comment: .open(your_file_name_here) *

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an /assets folder to put your text file in. Then you have to make sure you have the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

After that, you can follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) to use the files

Comment: This answer makes no sense.  Please don't pull out random disjoint ideas from that document and combine them in illogical ways.  The poster should read the document themselves; if they have trouble implementing they can revise their question.